# R class not updating

Tags: android

When I create a new activity All the code is generated. But **R.java** class is not updated.
Please can anyone come to my rescue. I am about to finish this project. Its the error near Activity_maininfo.

```
public class Maininfo extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maininfo);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.maininfo, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: try to clean the project. Check your xml for errors. R may not build when the xml files contains error.

Comment: Delete R file then clean and re-build.

Comment: try to add another menu file. may be error in menu file.

Comment: Also check that none of your resource file names has a **capital letter** in it.

Comment: if your resource file names has a capital letter, that error may be shown in the console. check console.

Comment: This name was generated by eclipse sdk,

Answer (score 1):

One of the following should work

- Project -> Clean,
- Right click -> Fix Project Properties
- Check all of your XML
- Maybe try restarting Eclipse